# C++ Function pointer of instance objects

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a simple template class that has two function pointers and a value. One pointer is a comparison operator and the other is of an object (for instance getX()).

Header:

```
template<class T>
class A {

public:
    A(T (*function)(), const bool (*op)(T,T),const T value) : 
        function(function), value(value), op(op){}
    bool valid();

private:
    T value;
    T (*function)();
    bool (*op)(T, T);
};
```

CPP:

```
#include "A.h"

template<class T>
bool A<T>::valid(){
    return (op(function(),value));
}
```

So if you created an instance of A:

```
A<float> a = A<float>(x->getX,operator==,20);
```

When valid is called is would be equivalent to:

```
x->getX() == 20;
```

The actual header/class definitions work fine. The problem is when creating an instance of A; it doesn't work. I figure this is because of the 'x->getX' but is there a way to do what I want?

Thanks.

EDIT::

The exact compiler error is the following:

....\Classes\Objects\B.cpp:42: error: no matching function for call to 'A::A(unresolved overloaded function type, unresolved overloaded function type, float)'
....\Classes\Objects/A.h:30: note: candidates are: A::A(T (*)(), const bool (*)(T, T), T) [with T = float]
....\Classes\Objects/A.h:26: note:                 A::A(const A&)

Please note: the 'x->getX' returns a float

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Function pointers are not functors. A functor is a class that overloads `operator()`.

Comment: Changed to function pointer. And by 'doesn't work' I mean it doesn't compile when creating an instance of A.

Comment: Paste in the exact compiler error(s).

Comment: `getX` is a method of some class. `x` is an object of that class. You can't pass `x.getX` as a pointer to normal function. It doesn't work in C++, like delegates in C#. The easiest way I can think of, to get the result you want is to make a wrapper. There must be some idiomatic way of doing it in C++, but you need someone who knows the language to tell you about it.

Comment: Added the compiler error.

Comment: @MaciejHehl I'm aware that that's the problem however I have no idea how to get around it. I tried passing the object and then calling the function on the object but that didn't work;;;

Comment: Why are you writing such code that is very difficult to read? It should have a narrative. Probably a better solution exists.

Comment: @EdHeal I don't know what you mean by difficult to read or having a narrative. =w=

Comment: @aoi - What is this class trying to achieve? Why are you complicating things using templates/pointers to functions?

Comment: One more remark. In garbage collected languages there is no problem with object lifetime. A delegate can have a reference to an object, on which it is supposed to call a method and that object will be kept alive as long, as needed. So yo can make a delegate for `x.getX` and use it as a regular function. In C++ the lifetime of objects matters. If `a` outlives `x` you have a fundamental problem. The question is if `a` can make a copy of `x` to store internaly. I think there is no general solution because of that lifetime problem.

Comment: @EdHeal It's for an event system for a game. Events have triggers and the like. However, I cannot hardcode the triggers in and triggers aren't set when the event is created. Furthermore, I have to check 'are all the triggers true?'

Comment: @aoi - That does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++11:

The way to do what you want is to use [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Also, if you want to pass as an argument comparison operators for basic types (int, float ...) you can use the `Comparison function objects` defined in the <[functional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional)> header (std::less, std::greater ...)

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, typename BinaryPredicate>
class A {

public:
    A(std::function<T()> function, BinaryPredicate pred,const T value) : 
        function_(function), pred_(pred), value_(value){}
    bool valid();

private:
    std::function<T()> function_;
    BinaryPredicate    pred_;
    T                  value_;
};

template<class T, typename BinaryPredicate>
bool A<T, BinaryPredicate>::valid(){
    return (pred_(function_(), value_));
}

class X {

   private:
   float val_;

   public:
   X(float val) : val_(val) {}

   float getX() {return val_;}
};

int main(void)
{
   X x(20);

   A<float, std::equal_to<float>> a(std::bind(&X::getX, &x), std::equal_to<float>(), 20);

   std::cout << std::boolalpha << a.valid() << std::endl;

   return (0);
}
```